# Radgrid add new record data checking

Tags: telerik, radgrid

In a Radgrid, how do I keep the add new record open when someone clicks the save button and I check to make sure the data is all in the correct format or valid?  I want the add new record to stay open after I tell them the data is not valid and also keep the values they have already entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the edit template of the Grid, you can always use the Validators. The edit form will not post if the validators don't pass.

You can take a look at the following demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/validation/defaultcs.aspx

When you add a new record - notice that UnitPrice is a required field. if you don't enter that the update button wont fire the postback.

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.

```
protectedvoidrdgdr1_InsertCommand(objectsender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
    TextBox OrderText=(TextBox)editItem["UniqueName"].Controls[0]

    if(OrderText.Text=="correct")
    {

        //insert the data in the database
    }
    else
    {
        e.Canceled = true;  
    }
}
```